# Variadic templates operator

Tags: c++, c++17, variadic-templates

Can somebody explain these statements?
What those operator (Eg: **, + ...**) does here?

1:  Sum of args

```
template <typename... Args>
int function(Args... args)
{
    return (args + ...);
}
```

2: Comma operator

```
template <typename... Args>
int function(Args... args)
{
    ((std::cout << args),...);
}
```

3: General case

```
template <typename... Args>
int function(Args... args)
{
    otherfunction(args...);
}
```

I know which case gives what results but I actually want to know how it works.
Thanks in advance❤️

Comment: 1. and 2. are [fold expressions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold), 3. is a [pack expansion](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack#Pack_expansion) (note the lack of an operator and dedicated parentheses).

Comment: What do you mean by "how it works"?  That is a very vague question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `(args + ...)` expands to `(args#0 + args#1 + args#2 + .....args#n)`
2. `((std::cout << args),...)` expands to `(((std::cout << args#0),std::cout << args#1) std::cout << args#n)`
3. `otherfunction(args...)` args is a expanded argument like `(args#0, args#1,...)`